# Understanding how the switch statement works in C - am I missing something?

Tags: c, switch-statement

It gives no error but the switch statement always goes to the default case. I didn't paste the functions for the sake of concision.

I was advised to break my programs into subroutines, but is structured programming always better? Even if it takes more line of code and longer to execute?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef M_PI
#define PI M_PI
#else
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288420
#endif // M_PI

int getData(int op);
float degreesToRadians(float angle);
float sine(float degrees);
float cosine(float degrees);
float tangent(float degrees);
float sineInverse(float degrees);
float cosineInverse(float degrees);
float tangentInverse(float degrees);

int main(void)
{
    float degrees;
    int op;

    getData(op);

    printf("Enter the angle in degrees: ");
    scanf("%f", &degrees);

    degreesToRadians(degrees);

    switch(op)
    {
    case 1:
        sine(degrees);
        break;

    case 2:
        cosine(degrees);
        break;

    case 3:
        tangent(degrees);
        break;

    case 4:
        sineInverse(degrees);
        break;

    case 5:
        cosineInverse(degrees);
        break;

    case 6:
        tangentInverse(degrees);
        break;

    default:
        printf("You entered an invalid option!");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248360/discussion-on-question-by-haris-salam-understanding-how-the-switch-statement-wor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the switch statement is correct. The switch expression, `op` here, is evaluated once, and compared with the constant expressions `1: 2:` etc, and you have a `default:` catch-all for when there is no match.

However, if you *always* end up in the default clause, this would be indicative of your case expressions *never* matching the `op` expression's value.  Note that you have written code with "undefined behavior" - because `op` is not defined anywhere. (This needs to be fixed.)

As far as I can tell, you are trying to retrieve a value from `getData()` by passing it an operand `op`.  However, getData() is declared as *returning an int parameter* but you don't use any returned value.  The variable `op` will **not** have its value changed after the call to getData() because you are *passing-by-value.*  (If you had passed by reference, for example a pointer, the getData() function *could* change the value of `op` for you.) Unfortunately, you haven't included getData() in the example code so we can't tell what its purpose is.

Similarly, you are passing the `degrees` variable to a conversion function but your are **not** using the converted value.  As you can see, all of the `float` functions declared at the top of the file will *return* `float` values.  You should use these returned values.

Suggestion:  Use the value returned by getData() and the floating point functions:

```
int data;
int op = ...;  // op must be defined!
float radians;
float trig_value;

data = getData(op);

radians = degreesToRadians(degrees);

switch (data) {
    ...
    trig_value = sine(radians);
}
```